# Facebook timeline/ news feed resizes external link thumbnails weirdly

Tags: facebook

When sharing a link with thumbnail images on timeline or news feed, usually regardless of the original image size ( however small), Facebook resets the images to something else that many times only half of the image is displayed or if entire image is displayed it is re-sized and as a result gets blurred! so what is this magic size to which we can set our website thumbnail images so that they don't get resided or degraded when shared on Facebook?100X100? 93X97?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook wants an `og:image` to be at least 200px on a a side, and with an aspect ratio smaller than 3:1. There is no maximum size for images.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by 200px a "side"? Width or Height?

Comment: Both width and height need to be 200px or larger.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be at least 200px in each dimension. Here is a link at which you can enter your website link for validation to see what the problems are: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/